# Passing arguments to nested newcommands

Tags: macros, errors, nesting

I thought that doubling hashes was sufficient to pass arguments to nested `\newcommand`.

```
\newcommand{\notice}[1]{
  \vspace{10px}
  \textbf{#1:}
  \begin{quotation}
    ##1
  \end{quotation}}

\newcommand{\hint}[1]{
  \notice{Hint}
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? The above produces the following error:

> "You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode."

Comment: This is not what is typically considered "nested". What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: In particular, if you replace `##1` by `#1` does it do what you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\notice}[2]{
  \vspace{10px}
  \textbf{#1:}
  \begin{quotation}
    #2
  \end{quotation}}

\newcommand{\hint}[1]{%
  \notice{Hint}{#1}%
}
```

You'll need the double hashes only if you `\def` something in a `\def`.

Answer (score 8):

What you've done is put the string `#1` inside the quotation.  Such an operation only makes sense if you are *defining* a macro inside of another one, and you want that macro to make reference to its *own* first argument rather than have the `#1` of the outer macro substituted.  For example, in:

```
\newcommand\macroia[1]{\renewcommand\macroii[1]{#1}}
\newcommand\macroib[1]{\renewcommand\macroii[1]{##1}}
\providecommand\macroii{}
```

the call `\macroia{xyz}` results in `\macroii{#1} = xyz`, i.e. it ignores its own argument and just prints whatever `\macroia` saw, while the call `\macroia{xyz}` results in `\macroii{#1} = #1`; i.e. it ignores the argument to `\macroia` and just echoes whatever it is passed when expanded.

Answer (score 6):

I'm doing some guesswork here. I believe that you want a boldface header to some text typeset with narrower line width. What you need is a new environment, not a new command:

```
\newenvironment{notice}[1]
  {\par\medskip\textbf{#1}\begin{quotation}}
  {\end{quotation}
```

so that you can input somethin like

```
\begin{notice}{Hint}
This is a very useful hint for solving the problem.
\end{notice}
```

The result won't be pretty, though. I'd place the heading inside the text:

```
\newenvironment{notice}[1]
  {\begin{quotation}\noindent\textbf{#1}\\*\ignorespaces}
  {\end{quotation}}
```

(same syntax as before). Also `\hint` should be an environment:

```
\newenvironment{hint}
  {\begin{notice}{Hint}}
  {\end{notice}}
```

Don't use spaces at random (`\vspace{10px}`, for instance), but above all *don't* use `px` to specify lengths. This is a unit that doesn't have a fixed value and is definitely not analogous to what the similar unit does in HTML or CSS.